# Update MVC3 model with a link in a webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, postback, webgrid

I am using C#.NET MVC3.  I have a field being shown in a webgrid like this:

```
grid.Column("MyField", "MyFieldHeader")
```

I need to create an HTML link based on the value in this field with the following properties:

1. The field value is the item being hyper-linked.
2. The link must update a public property in the model that rendered the view (write the linked value to the model).
3. Link must post back to self

How do I achieve this?  I am using the standard ASPX syntax (not Razor)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an HTML Helper and pass @Url.Action  as a string to generate the url.